# Убрать php ставки из js кода на странице и перенсти во внешний файл

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Ситуация такая: на многих страницах сайта вместе с HTML кодом идет `<script>`. Сейчас хочется перенести JS во внешние файлы, но в JS есть вставки PHP.

Я так понимаю, во внешний скрипт нужно будет передавать в качестве параметров функций значения, определенные в PHP, и все равно нужно будет писать `<script>` со вставкой PHP на странице.

Есть ли смысл тогда изменять?

page.html:

```
<head>
   <script scr="page.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
…
<? $options = json_encode([...]); ?>
<script>
    PageEdit(<? $options ?>);
</script>
</body>

page.js
function PageEdit(options)
{
 …
}
```

Comment: А почему так нельзя: `var options = <?=json_encode()?>;`, т.е. сохранять JSON в переменную и использовать её?

Comment: @XelaNimed Подразумевается что PageEdit объект с различными функциями для текущей страницы и options как глобальная переменная будет